# How do I scroll to a specific symbol inside TextView's text

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I have `TextView` nested `ScrollView`. The `TextView` contains an HTML formatted text. The Size of the text can be changed by the user.

The text is divided into parts:

```
Part1 till <br> Part2 till , Part3 till <br>
```

Each part has different length.

How do I scroll to `Part2 till ,`?

[image: Look this]

Have example ...

```
tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
tView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

// tView.append(text + "\n");
tView.scrollTo();
final Layout layout = tView.getLayout(); // <-- THIS RETURN null 
if(layout != null){
int scrollDelta = layout.getLineBottom(tView.getLineCount() - 1) - tView.getScrollY() - tView.getHeight();
     if(scrollDelta > 0)  tView.scrollBy(0, scrollDelta);
}
```

Comment: see `android.text.Layout` API on how to get vertical line for any offset position

Comment: Can you exactly tell what you really want? Do you want to scroll to a specific line or to a tag or substring/text?

Comment: Click for see -> [How it should works](https://content.foto.my.mail.ru/mail/wonderdog/_mypagephoto/h-733.jpg)

Comment: did you see the `android.text.Layout` API? what is unclear?

Comment: @pskink I think the OP is looking for code. :D

Comment: @Sufian with no effort? no pain, no gain...

Comment: @pskink although still got 2 upvotes.:P

Comment: `tView.scrollTo();` this is not correct. The method with this name takes 2 int arguments. And for that `null` thing, [see the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLayout()).